# Export Hierarchy Viewer's metrics

Tags: android, profiling

Is it possible to export metrics (layout times) provided from Hierarchy Viewer to some text format?

Is there some other tool providing this possibility? We want to use this metrics in our regression tests suite.

[image]

Comment: `adb shell uiautomator dump` - but only ui tree can be dumped imho, not layout times

Comment: Yep, I know about it. Unfortunately, it doesn't export timings.